# How to handle "Loader" and "No result found" message when filtering data in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using React and Firebase to build an ecommerce, I just want to set the **Loader** at the right time and the **"No result found"** message when I'm filtering the data through input search and the **searchKey** is not matching any product.

So the target is: handle both the situations and never show an empty page when there is no result after a search by input field.

The category filter is working properly, but if you suggest any change you're welcome.

I was trying to make a separate function for each search, but at the moment I'm handling the **setState** functions directly in the **JSX** (as you can see in the **HomePage** component). Still, if you think that is better to separate the logic from the JSX, you're welcome.

I know is a very basic problem to solve, but it always confuse me. If you can help me it would be awesome guys.

*This is the* **getProducts()** *function to retrieve products from firebase/firestore*

```
import { collection, getDocs, getDoc, doc } from "firebase/firestore";
import DB from '../../firebase';

const getProducts = async (setProducts) => {

    try {
        const productsFromFB = await getDocs(collection(DB, 'products'))
        let productsContainer = []
        productsFromFB.forEach(doc => {
            const productWithID = {
                id: doc.id,
                ...doc.data()
            }
            productsContainer.push(productWithID)
        })
        setProducts(productsContainer)

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

**HomePage** *component, where there's the issue*

```
// React stuff
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

// components
import { Layout, Product, Loader, FilterInputs } from '../components/components-provider/components-provider'

// functions
import { getProducts } from './pages-provider/pages-functions'

const HomePage = () => {

    const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
    const [searchKey, setSearchKey] = useState("")
    const [category, setCategory] = useState("")

    useEffect(() => {
        getProducts(setProducts)
    }, [])

    return (
        <Layout>
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <FilterInputs
                        searchKey={searchKey}
                        category={category}
                        setSearchKey={setSearchKey}
                        setCategory={setCategory}
                     />

/// HERE I NEED TO HANDLE BOTH LOADER AND NO RESULTS FOUND
                    {products.length > 0 ? products
                        .filter(toFilterItem => toFilterItem.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchKey))
                        .filter(toFilterCategory => toFilterCategory.category.toLowerCase().includes(category))
                        .map(product => (
                            <Product product={product} key={product.id} />
                        )) : <Loader />}
                </div>
            </div>
        </Layout>
    )
}

export default HomePage
```

**FilterInputs** *component*

```
import React from 'react'

const FilterInputs = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="d-flex">
            <input
                type="text"
                value={props.searchKey}
                onChange={(e) => props.setSearchKey(e.target.value)}
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Search Items..." />

            <select
                onChange={(e) => props.setCategory(e.target.value)}
                value={props.category}
                className="form-control">
                <option value="">All</option>
                <option value="home">Home</option>
                <option value="food">Food</option>
                <option value="electronics">Electronics</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    )
}

export default FilterInputs
```

Comment: You can try storing another variable that stores if data has been fetched or not.

Comment: Hi, have you resolved the issue?